# What kind of web MVC pattern is this?

Tags: web-services, model-view-controller, design-patterns, web-applications, coldfusion

I was wondering what kind of MVC pattern the illustration below is. We are developing a web application according to this pattern using ColdFusion and it goes pretty well so far. But is it even some kind of MVC at all?

[image]

A frontend page usually consists of:
- including the corresponding gateways (each model component has its own gateway with dedicated functionality)
- using the provided GATEWAY struct (contains components, arrays, structs etc. representing the desired data) to render output
- simple flow control (if/else/loops) to iterate through the provided data or distinguish view states
- if required: build forms (POST to same page) and name their field names according to GATEWAY specifications

The GATEWAY file (always separated from frontend page) validates the request (usually POST data) and takes care of the data retrieval (i.e. selects/inserts/updates on database). Usually the GATEWAY requests data regardless of actions (evaluation of runetime data like SESSION). All operations are fail-safe, so either there is data in the resulting struct or the data is empty. Either way, two arrays (success, errors) in the struct provide a log of all performed actions during the processing to react accordingly on the frontend page. Most data is provided as components (objects), but all in all it is not a fully object-orientied approach. The only thing they have in common is: they all describe input parameters (GET, POST, Session, Cookie) and outgoing parameters, like a (RESTful) web service.

I came up with a lot of ideas about the used pattern, but I wasn't able to match it in all regards yet.

Comment: This seems like more a philosophical question rather than a programming one? Is there really a concrete answer that you are looking for?

Comment: One of my colleagues questioned this approach and suggested to use fully object-oriented MVC (divided into three separat components instead of a file based module that handles model and controller at the same time). My boss asked me to clarify this pattern and I'm not sure if I can justify it by calling the method "MVC in a different way". I thought someone with more experience might see a clear similarity.

Comment: Wouldn't you justify a concept based on its merit rather than what it's called?

Comment: The controller and the model _should_ be separate - otherwise it's simply not MVC.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you go fully OO or not, but what you should do is investigate [FW/1](http://fw1.riaforge.org) and [ColdBox](http://coldbox.org) - pick either of those frameworks and use them to structure your application. (The only reason NOT to use an accepted framework would be if you can explain and agree with your colleagues why your particular application requires a different/superior structure which isn't possible with one of these frameworks - which it very likely doesn't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my mind the most important thing MVC provides is the separation between your view and your model.  By doing this you can completely replace the view or the model without having to make changes to the other.  In fact the main purpose of the controller is to act as the man in the middle between the two.  Need to switch database servers, you shouldn't have to change out your view, or even your controller really.  Need to create a new view, or replace the view you have, again you shouldn't have to mess with your model or controller really.

Ask yourself those questions about this proposed framework your going to create and the answers should come easy.